# How to reduce dataset for plotting

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, java

I have a large dataset that contains a lot of noise that I would like to eliminate in order to reduce the size of the dataset and speed up data visualization.

I was thinking to reduce the number of datapoints by selecting data points with similar values and replacing them a single point.

Let's say I have the following dataset and each datapoint has a timestamp associated with it:

```
[0.1, 0.11, 0.08, 0.065 .... 0.5, 1.2, 5, 5.1, 5.01, 5.05, 4.98, ...]
```

I want replace the first N numbers with a single value, since I'm not getting any useful information, then I keep the ramp up, then when I get to 5, replace the next N numbers with a single value and so forth.

I was thinking to use a rolling variance that would reset if the value crosses some threshold. As long as the values are within that band, they'll be replaced by an average?

I guess another option is to sample the data and plot that?

What would be the best way to do that? It's been a long while since I had to do any statistics so I'm having hard time convincing myself that my approach will work.

**Edit:**
Maybe calculate the mean absolute deviation, then divide by the mean of the sample (the sample being the first N points), then if that's within the acceptable range(let's say 1%), move to the next N points (maybe with some overlap?).

I'm currently prototyping in python but will end implementing the algorithm in java.

Comment: Do you have more data than you need to answer your question or is there noise that you need to remove?  If you simply need to visualize the larger pattern you could sample the existing data.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482889/get-random-sample-from-list-while-maintaining-ordering-of-items